# another grails urlmapping question

Tags: grails, url-mapping

ok, so i asked, and got an answer on how to make a single controller instance case-insensitive vis-a-vis urls. I can do

```
"/mycontroller/$action?/$id?"(controller: "myController")
```

so when an app outside tries to reference  link in our app, their lowercase urls ( :( sigh ) will work.

I need to extend this to include actions as well. So the question is, following the above approach, do i need put a url mapping in for each action?

```
/mycontroller/methodone/(controller: "myController", action: methodOne)
/mycontroller/methodtwo/(controller: "myController", action: methodTwo)
```

Something like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the question below which I have answered and included source code

[How to make my URL mapping case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809588/how-to-make-my-url-mapping-case-insensitive/3295614#3295614)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure to calculate the action (or other parameters) programmatically:

```
"/mycontroller/$a?/$id?" {
    controller = 'myController'
    action = { params.a?.toLowerCase() }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt this convert the action being called to lowercase?  On the controller, the action is camel cased.  So a 

/mycontroller/myaction

needs to be converted to 

/myController/myAction  

to work

Comment: You're right, I read your question wrong -- I thought you wanted to go from camel- to lower-case. To go the other way, you'd need to get the list of actions for the controller (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956294/reading-out-all-actions-in-a-grails-controller), and then build out a map of lower-case to camel-case names. Rather than putting all that code in your url-mappings config, though, you'd probably want to map "/mycontroller/$a?/$id?" to a new action in MyController, and have that action run the lower-to-camel code and forward the request on to the camel-cased action.